# Changing strip timing accuracy from floats to integers (VSE)

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am using Blender for my video editing work ever since version 2.79. Now with 3.4.1 though, I find the accuracy of the X-coordinates of strips on the timeline has been changed to decimals, as opposed to integers in previous versions. (Strip properties / Time / Start gives me "1.0" instead of just "1"). Any idea where can I change that back to integers?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the VSE, but the Strip > Time > Start setting is displayed as a time (00:00:00:00) as expected rather than a float on the N-panel here and has been since at least version 2.83. You aren't talking about the View menu > Show Seconds checkbox toggle (also available via Ctrl-T) are you?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your reply! No, I'm not talking about the seconds toggle ctrl-T, but indeed about the Strip > Time > Start setting displayed as a time (00:00:00:00). If you click on that, the current 3.4.1 version will return "0.0" instead of just "0" as before. Normally I couldn't care less, but this makes it impossible to grab & move strips frame by frame by clicking on the arrows to the left and right of the displayed time. This just doesn't work anymore. So any help here would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm... I see what you mean! The arrows work in 2.83 and 2.93 but not in 3.3.3 LTS or 3.4. I'd report that as a bug via the Help > Report a Bug menu in 3.4 and mention that it doesn't work in 3.3 either although that LTS version actually goes out of support this spring.

Comment: Thanks John, I'll do that.

Comment: Done! (bug report nr. 106108)

Comment: Good! Incidentally it's 2.93 that goes out of support this year. Having checked again, 3.3 LTS is supported until September 2024.

Comment: That was confirmed as a bug and has been fixed [here](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/8ad0935ed6ab0945dfcee572e747a6ab87fc9f7b). This didn't make it into Blender3.3.5 but will hopefully be in version 3.5 when it comes out later this week.